# Долго загружается Activity с ViewPager2, в котором загружаются 12 наполненных фрагментов

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Уже долгое время ищу ответ на вопрос, который меня мучает. В общем, делаю приложение на Android в Android Studio. С главного Activity перехожу на второе Activity при нажатии на кнопку.
Так вот на втором TabLayout и ViewPager2. В OnCreate создаю Adapter для pager, подвязываю к TabLayout через TabLayoutMediator. В адаптере создаю 12 фрагментов. На каждом из фрагментов от 10 до 12 кнопок и TextView, наложенный на каждую кнопку сверху.

В общем, ооооочень долго грузится второе Activity. Я то понимаю, что долго грузится из-за того, что рисуются все Fragment. Я пробовал менять pageOffLimit у pager, чтобы все фрагменты прогружались и не удалялись при перелистывании, но тогда долго грузится Acticity. Но, если я делаю pageOffLimit по умолчанию, то грузится быстрее, но тогда при перелистывании начинает подлагивать приложение, потому что фрагменты каждый раз заново рисуются.

Так вот. Можно ли каким-то способом решить эту проблему?

Просто делаю игрушку текстовую. Видел одно приложении «Бомжара» в Google Play. Так вот вон там, все работает идеально, а принцип тот же. Много фрагментов, но все загружается быстро и плавно перелистывается.

Подскажите, что можно придумать? Уже мозг сломал)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.